# When compiled with -O2, program skips assignment

Tags: c++, optimization

I was writing a code to solve a programming challenge, but when I submitted the code it was giving a runtime error. Someone told me to try compiling it using -O2 to see if I could locate the issue.

Turns out that something really creepy happens: when executed, the optimized version simply skips the assignment of one crucial variable!

The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const unsigned int primos[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997};
const unsigned int nprimos = 168;

struct numprim {
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned int qtdd;
};

numprim numeros[1000];

bool
compare(numprim &a, numprim &b) {
    return (a.qtdd < b.qtdd || (a.qtdd == b.qtdd && a.num > b.num));
}

void quickSort(int esquerda, int direita)
{
    int i, j;
    numprim x, y;
    i = esquerda;
    j = direita;
    x = numeros[(esquerda + direita) / 2];

    while(i <= j)
    {
        while(compare(numeros[i], x) && i < direita)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while(compare(x, numeros[j]) && j > esquerda)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if(i <= j)
        {
            y = numeros[i];
            numeros[i] = numeros[j];
            numeros[j] = y;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if(j > esquerda)
    {
        quickSort(esquerda, j);
    }
    if(i < direita)
    {
        quickSort(i, direita);
    }
}


int main() {
    unsigned int i, j;
    unsigned int tmp, num;

    for(i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        numeros[i].qtdd = 1;
        numeros[i].num = num = i+1;

        // TODO: Verificar se ha como sair pela primeira condicao, e o que fazer
        j = 0;
        while((j < nprimos) && (num % primos[j] > 0))
            ++j;

        for(tmp = 0; num % primos[j] == 0; ++tmp)
            num /= primos[j];

        numeros[i].qtdd = (tmp+1)*numeros[num-1].qtdd;
    }

    quickSort(0, 999);

    cin >> tmp;
    for(i = 1; i <= tmp; ++i) {
        cin >> num;

        cout << "Case " << i << ": " << numeros[num-1].num << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ 4.9.2 compiled using the command `g++ -O2 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -o ordem ordem.cpp`

When run in gdb, strangely, just at the first iteration of the "for" (main function, the `num` gets a different value than the `numeros[i].num` field. I also tried to move things, rename stuff, and other desperate measures, but none worked.

I simply cannot understand what caused this behaviour. Would someone please help me? I was going to show this code to my students...

Comment: The problem I was trying to solve can be found here: http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1109

Comment: clang compiled it successfully with -O2 , g++ failed throwing floating point exception

Comment: Debugger producing hallucinogenic results on optimized code is nothing new. Don't trust everything you see.

Comment: How exactly did you discover that `numeros[i].num` and `num` have different values? Did you print out the values? Or did you use a debugger? Note that using a debugger on an optimised program almost always gives misleading results, even if the program runs correctly.

Comment: No idea why someone told you to turn on optimisations to troubleshoot; that's nonsense!

Comment: @araruna: Your link wants me to register :(

Comment: The conclusion is: please debug it without optimisation, and tell us where the runtime error occurs and with what output.

Comment: Yeah, I used a debugger... =\
Well, I took the case where `i = 0` out of the loop and it _seems_ to have solved the problem (but what was it again?)

Comment: @PJTraill: When no optimisation is set, nothing strange happens. The question was why the strange behaviour when optimisation _is_ set, so it is of no use to debug without it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while((j < nprimos) && (num % primos[j] > 0))
    ++j;
```

One way for this `while` loop to terminate is when `j == nprimos` (when `i == 0` and therefore `num == 1`, for instance; obviously 1 isn't divisible by any prime number.)

In this case the access to `primos[j]` in your subsequent `for` loop will be out of bounds.

Comment: I don't know if I see it, but just an observation: `nprimos` is always 168 (it is const, and defined globally at the beginning). So, when that happens, it kinda means that `num` is divisible by all primes between 1 and 1000, which is impossible due to the problem restrictions.

Comment: @araruna when you access `primos[j]` when j is 168 it will read outside the bounds of the `primos` array. Anything could happen when you do that, in this case when compiled with optimization the next value happens to be 0 and you get a divide by 0 error. When compiled without optimization you (un)luckily get some other value that won't cause a divide by 0.

Comment: @araruna No, `j == nprimos` when `num` is *not* divisible by all primes between 1 and 1000. And there's a number in that range with that property: 1.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are absolutely right, @T.C.!!! Now I see it!
Sorry, but after 10p.m. I just cannot think straight (it was 11p.m. when I posted the question...)